# Using CA certificate in mqtt paho

Tags: c++, mqtt, pahocpp

I'm writing application that collect some hardware inputs and send it to MQTT broker.
Currently, broker use credentials only, no SSL, and all works fine.
(Program is written in C++, Linux. I use Paho MQTT library- by including source code, not compiled library)
But the next feature that I need to develop is TLS- protected connection.
I have a pem-formatted CA root certificate file. In MQTT.fx application I set path to this file to "CA Certificate file" field and all works. But in code, I can't find how I can set this file.

My code:

```
//initialize options
    MQTTClient client;
    char * address = "our broker address:8883";
    char * clientID = "Our ID";
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_SSLOptions ssl_opts = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;
    conn_opts.MQTTVersion =MQTTVERSION_3_1_1;

    conn_opts.serverURIcount  =0;
    conn_opts.serverURIs = NULL;
    conn_opts.username= creds->getUser(); 
    conn_opts.password= creds->getPwd();  
    
    // starting ssl setting
    ssl_opts = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;
    
    ssl_opts.CApath = [filepath]/ca.pem; // I tried to use trustStore and keyStore- the same effect
    
    ssl_opts.sslVersion = 3;
    ssl_opts.ssl_error_cb = SSL_err_handler;
    conn_opts.ssl = & ssl_opts;
    ssl_opts.struct_version =1;
    conn_opts.struct_version = 1;
    MQTTClient_create(&client, address, clientID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL );
    int rc;
    if ( (rc = MQTTClient_connect( client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf( "failed to connect, code is %d\n", rc);
        return rc;
    }
    // continue execution
```

MQTTClient_connect returns -1- bad socket

Where I wrong?

Comment: The documentation says that `CApath` exists only for `struct_version >= 2` and that this points to a directory (and not a file). Imho the documentaion for this client library lacks some maintenance

Comment: Yes. But I tried another fields and it not helps.

Comment: You can try to set `ssl_error_context` to get some more info why this fails. But again for this callback documentation says `struct_version >= 3` is required for this paramter

Answer (score 0):

I spent half a day on a similar issue. I thought using the SSL options would tell the paho library functions I was relying on encryption and decryption. No such luck. It turned out I needed to prepend the address with "ssl://" e.g.

```
char *address = "ssl://our broker address:8883"
```

and used that with:

```
conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = "/...path to.../certs/ca/ca.crt";
conn_opts.ssl->keyStore = "/...path to.../certs/client/client.pem";
```

Aside: I used bash cli to build the .pem with:

```
cat /...path to.../certs/client/client.{crt,key} > /...path to.../certs/client/client.pem
```

Which worked!